# How to do Model binding using JSON data in laravel blade template?

Tags: jquery, json, laravel, model-binding, laravel-blade

I am trying to view information of a specific user in Laravel. The user is selected from a drop down menu. I am trying to show this user's information using jQuery.

Here is the code for drop down list:

```
{{ Form::label('Field Force Select:' ) }}
<select name="field_force" id="ffID">
    <option value=""> --- Please Select a Field Force --- </option>
    @foreach($users as $user)
        <option value="{{ $user->id }}">
          {{ $user->first_name.' '.$user->last_name }}
        </option>
    @endforeach
</select>
```

and here is the code in route file for `$users` :

```
public function getAccount() {
    $group = Sentry::findGroupByName('Field Force');
    $users = Sentry::findAllUsersInGroup($group);
    $currentUser = Sentry::getUser();
    return View::make('users/account', 
       array('as' => 'account'))
              ->with(compact('users', 'currentUser')
      );
}
```

After selecting one user from the drop down list, I used this code to get user specific information:

```
<script>
$('#ffID').change(function(){
var infoShare= $('.infoStorage');
    $.get("{{ url('api/dropDownUserInformation')}}",
        { option: $(this).val() },
        function(data) {

            $.each(data, function(index, element) {
                alert( element.id );

           });
        });
});
```

and here is the route file for `api/dropDownUserInformation` :

```
Route::get('api/dropDownUserInformation',function(){
   $fieldForceID=Input::get('option');
   $invoices=Invoice::where('sender_id','=',$fieldForceID)->get();
   return Response::json($invoices);
});
```

So far this code work fine but when i tried to access data from one table to another through model binding it does not allow me to access user specific information. Here is the **Invoice** model:

```
<?php
class Invoice extends \Eloquent {
    protected $fillable = [];

    public function sales() {
        return $this->hasMany('Sale', 'invoice_id','sender_id');
    }

    public function accounts() {
        return $this->belongsTo('SaleAccount');
    }
    public function senderName() {
        return $this->belongsTo('User','sender_id');
    }
}
```

I wanted to access `users` table, using `SenderName()`. So I wrote this code in my script:

```
alert( element.SenderName.first_name );
```

In console it shows this error:
**TypeError: element.SenderName is undefined**

I am able do model binding by returning some variable from route file normally.

Here is the code in route file:

```
public function getUserInfo() {
    $invoice=Invoice::where('id','=',1)->get();
    return View::make('users/account', array(
           'as' => 'account'))->with(compact('invoice'));
}
```

And here is the code in *View* file:

```
@foreach($invoice as$inv)
   {{ $inv->senderName->first_name}}
@endforeach
```

It works fine, but I don't know how to do it after returning data in JSON format.

Answer (score 1):

I would change the Route:

```
Route::get('api/dropDownUserInformation',function(){
    $fieldForceID = Input::get('option');
    $invoices = Invoice::where('sender_id','=',$fieldForceID)
        ->join('users', 'invoices.sender_id', '=', 'users.id')->get();
    return Response::json($invoices);
});
```

That should be accessible as follows in your jquery function...

```
 alert( element.first_name );
```